# Error while Using OpenAerostruct and OpenMDAO together

Tags: openmdao

When I run the code given in the document on combined aero and structure I go this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matlib'

Based on the previous answer I had got, I tried to install the updated version of 'matplotlib' , but this has not solved the problem. Any help will greatly help me as I am a FORTRAN era person and a new convert to Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but please view this answer as a comment and I'll edit it once I can answer more properly.

That sounds like a `numpy` installation issue. Could you please post the entire error trace that you get when you try running the command?

Additionally, what system are you on (Windows, Mac, Linux), how did you install Python, and have you tried any other Python-based code that you can get to work successfully?

Edit: the most recent version of OpenAeroStruct has been modified to avoid this issue altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use an intel compiled version of python and numpy can't find an necessary underlying library. Something is messed up in your python/numpy install.

This has nothing to do with OpenAeroStruct or OpenMDAO. If you can't fix your install, I suggest trying out the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) python distribution, which should have everything precompiled correctly.